# Customizing events in React Big Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

How to add menu button to calendar events??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, it can be done very easily. The calendar [has a corresponding prop](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/?path=/docs/props--components) for displaying each event.:

```
<Calendar 
  components={{ 
    event: (event) => <EventComponent {...event} /> 
  }} 
/>
```