# Angular Fullcalender - Custom context-menu on right click

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, contextmenu, fullcalendar-5

I am using Fullcalender version 5 in an angular project. I could already figure out how to prevent the default contextmenu when right-clicking on an event, by setting an eventlistener to each event via the *eventDidMount* property in the *CalenderOptions* object:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    ...
    eventDidMount: this.eventDidMount.bind(this),
    ...
}

eventDidMount(info) {
    info.el.addEventListener("contextmenu",  event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      //ID of the event - will be needed for setting the state later on
      console.log("eventDidMount", info.event.id);
      return false;
    }, false);
  }
```

I dont know however how to go further. When right-clicking on an event, I want to show a list of different states that can be selected (each of my events has a state that should be editable this way).

How can i open a custom context menu from this point on?

Comment: Get the position of the click, and display a component at this position. Use Angular's CDK to do that, they have some features that shuold help you out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092542/how-can-i-add-menu-button-for-events-in-the-fullcalendar - someone actually asked a fairly similar thing yesterday as well, and looks like they posted a solution too in a codesandbox. Maybe it's useful to you.

Comment: What MGX suggested worked fine for me. Thanks